# How to open screen wiith click on item in flatlist in react native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

> I want to open screen when i press one of this items (images). I need to open Player screen in my app, so it have to be different screen for each item. Is there way to do that? Please help me. I cant find any solution on Google. Here is my code:
>
> Here are my flatlist items (images):

```
class ReadingComponent extends Component {
    constructor(props: any) {
        super(props);
    }
    
    render() {
        
    let categories = [ 
        {
            name : "Category 1",
            img : require("../Assets/Slika.jpg"),
        },
        {
            name : "Category 2",
            img : require("../Assets/Slika.jpg"),
        },
        {
            name : "Category 3",
            img : require("../Assets/Slika.jpg"),
        },
      ];
```

> Flatlist:

```
return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <FlatList
                    data={categories}
                    showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
                    numColumns={categories.length / 5}
                    showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
                    renderItem = {({item, index}) => {
                        return (
                        <TouchableWithoutFeedback>
                        <Surface style={styles.surface} >
                            <ImageBackground
                            source={item.img} 
                            style={styles.img}
                            blurRadius={0.5}>
                        <Icon name="music" color="#fff" size={22}/>
                        <Text style={styles.name}>{item.name}</Text>
                            </ImageBackground>
                        </Surface>
                        </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
                        );
                    }}
                />
            </View>
            
        );    
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

2 things. First, you very rarely want to use TouchableWithoutFeedback. Users expect feedback when they touch something that they can interact with - such as a button.

If you are 100% sure you want it to be without feedback, then continue with that, but I think you likely will want TouchableOpacity instead.

The second thing is you are almost there. You need to add an `onPress` prop to your touchable tag. You will want to update your data source so that each '`item`' in it contains the information you need to be able to navigate to your correct screen. It may be as simple as including another variable named '`screenName`' or the like, or you could get as complicated as adding an entire function that you pass into your `onPress` event handler. Either way, you know your code better than I, but you just need to add a little data to your `categories` array.

EDIT:
Here is an example using the screenName approach mentioned above.

```
let categories = [ 
    {
        name : "Category 1",
        img : require("../Assets/Slika.jpg"),
        screenName: "PlayerScreen",
    },
```

```
    <TouchableOpacity
       onPress={() => {
          // navigate to screen named item.screenName
       }}
    >
```

Comment: Can you edit my code because I am new at react native so I am not sure I understand you?

Comment: Thank you...helped me a lot

Comment: If your question is answered, please select my answer.

Comment: I still have problem. I made everything like you said but when I run app on iOS Expo I cant open screen with press. I dont have errors but cant open screen.

Comment: Sorry, life has been crazy lately. It looks like your code is almost there, you just need to call your navigation function to navigate to the `screenName` you are storing.

Comment: Problem is I have to convert Class to Function, but I dont know how to do that.

Comment: I posted it here as answer, because it is solution for first problem, but still have to be changed.

Comment: If my answer helped you answer your original question, you should select my answer as the answer. Second, If you have a new problem, you really should post that as a new problem. Seeing as you are new, I'll look at it here, but my question is ... why does it need to be a function and not a class?

Comment: According to rules of hooks, it need to be a function. I am new at react native so I am not sure, but I read it on this site: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html

Comment: I posted it as new problem, but nobody gives me right solution. I saw you are good at this, so I asked you here

Comment: I fixed it. Thank you for your time anyway.

Comment: The answer on your other question is correct, incase you haven't seen it yet.

Comment: Yes, I seen that.

Answer (score 0):

Here is update of code.

Flatlist items:

```
let categories = [ 
        {
            name : "Category 1",
            img : require("../Assets/Slika.jpg"),
            screenName : "Player",
        },
```

onPress:

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress={() => item.screenName}}>
```